# React rerender every time page is visited

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing a performance issue with my app I have created and I am just trying to conceptualize a solution. I am fetching data from a database every time the page loads and distributing parts of the data I fetched to state. My issue is, upon the first load, that the data never really changes but each time I go back to the page a rerender occurs fetching the same data. What are some methods to stop this? Maybe fetch the data once and set it to something more permanent than state so I don't have to keep rerendering pages I've already been to. Is it possible to use a context to set isDataFetched and do something with that? I am not sure how to solve a conceptual issue such as this.

Here is an example of a component that fetches data but will keep rerendering everytime the page is visited regardless of whether or not data to fetch has changed:

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { ThemeContext } from "../contexts/ThemeContext";
import styles from "../styles/GroupListStyles";
import GroupItem from "./GroupItem";
import { LoggedInContext } from "../contexts/LoggedIn";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

function GroupList(props) {
  const [groupsState, setGroups] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const { isDarkMode } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const { token } = useContext(LoggedInContext);
  const { classes } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8181/groups", {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Token: token
      }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        setGroups(data.data);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, [token]);

  const removeGroup = (groupId) => {
    setGroups(groups => groups.filter(el => el._id !== groupId));
  }



console.log(groupsState);
  const handleDeleteGroupClick = (groupId) => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8181/groups/" + groupId, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Token: token
      },
      method: "DELETE"
    })
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
      console.log(data.data)
      removeGroup(groupId);
      })
  };
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <div className={classes.holder}>
        <div
          className={`${classes.table} ${
            isDarkMode ? classes.bgDark : classes.bgLight
          }`}
        >
          <div>
            Name <i className="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
          </div>
          <div>
            URL <i className="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
          </div>
          <div>
            Description <i className="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
          </div>

          <div>Actions</div>
        </div>

        {loading ? (
          <h1>Loading...</h1>
        ) : (
          groupsState.map(group => {
            return (
              <GroupItem
                name={group.name}
                url={group.url}
                description={group.description}
                id={group._id}
                key={group.name}
                handleClick={handleDeleteGroupClick}
              />
            );
          })
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(GroupList);
```

Comment: mind showing some code to help out on underlying issue?

Comment: A rerender (remount?) should definitely not trigger a new request to the server. Make the fetched data part of your *app* state, as opposed to a page's state, then simply pass it down to the page. (edit: if the page being reloaded *contains* the entire app, store the fetched data in localStorage)

Comment: This is where you would probably want to use Context instead of component state

Answer (score 0):

Redux is a good solution, Redux can manage the state of the App and you don't have to fetch the data every time you visit the page,

Here's the official Redux Documentation:

[enter link description here](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

With `redux` or `flux` you can keep a store where the `state` is shared globally and with that you can save if you had already fetched. Or more simply you can save `isDataFetched` in your component state

Answer (score 0):

Because after first page rendering you want to update page just when data is being updated then use Pure Component instead of normal Component, Pure Component will update page when props being change, It' just concept for more detail please use this ->  https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent,

There is no issue with redux or flux. For large data tables or large data set it's better to use Pure Component.