# How request API data in React only one time and not render the page every time that is visited?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, react-state-management, react-context

So in websites with multiple pages, where which one makes use of external data from an API, what is the best logical way to make the request only one time, when the page is loaded for the first time? So, for example, I go to the page ABOUT (using React Router) for the first time and it makes the Axios request and loads the data, then I change to the HOME page, and when I go back to ABOUT it does not load the data again.

Because what I currently do is a request every time the page loads and that's very clunky for user experience. I make the requests using Axios in the `componentDidMount` method.
Can React Hooks with Context API help to solve this?

I have seen this post, but remain confused:
[React rerender every time page is visited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59953643/react-rerender-every-time-page-is-visited)

Thanks in advance, sry if I couldn't be clearer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into caching - it will not require changes in your current code, but only when setting up axios. When you will make a request for the same data with little time changing since the last request, it will serve from cache instead of call the server.

An example for a library that can take care of caching in axios is [axios-cache-adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-cache-adapter).

Comment: That’s it, thanks! It is exactly what I needed, and I searched for more info and find this cool and easy to use library https://www.npmjs.com/package/swr

Answer (score 0):

That can be easily achieved using the `Link` component present in the `react-router-dom` package. Just replace your regular anchor tags which you use to navigate between pages to `<Link to="yourUrl" />` This way, state won't get refreshed everytime you visit a different page and will stay there unless you close the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Using Redux or a similar global state management tool (such as Context API) would be one solution for this. With Redux, you would be able to store the API data into global state, and then in your `componentDidMount` method, you could run the Axios request only if your corresponding global state value is empty.

Another solution involving Redux would be to have an omnipresent layout component, such as a Navbar, to be responsible for requesting all API data. If you position your Navbar outside of the React Router, then this component will not unmount itself when React Router brings you to a different page. Using this method, if you want to load in pertinent data upon accessing a page for the first time, but have it persist throughout the remainder of the session, you could have a `useEffect` with a dependency of the `useLocation().pathname` (from react-router-dom) that loads in API data, stores it globally, and only requests said data if it doesn't already have it.

Another side perk of using global state management is that your HTTP code, in most cases, will be abstracted out of the component and organized into some type of an "actions" folder that will make everything easier to manage.